# In Tritium, what are the differences between CSS and XPath selectors?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, moovweb, tritium

What are the advantages / disadvantages of the two different selectors?

Should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's primarily a matter of user preference.

To select the first child of all `<p>` elements, you'd do:

- `$("//p/*[1]")` in Xpath
- `$$("p > *:first-child")` in CSS

I prefer using Xpath, but YMMV.

Note that, internally, all CSS selectors are converted to Xpath. For example, the selector `$$("#one")` will be converted into `$(".//*[id='one']")`.

Comment: I read somewhere that CSS selectors are sometimes faster, but I think that's on client side DOM manipulation. Are there any metrics regarding performance of selectors in the Moovweb SDK?

Comment: As Aaron says in this response, the difference in CSS selector and Xpath selector performance is negligible. In both cases, you can scope your search to ensure faster performance.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few notes:

- indexing starts from 1 in XPath, so it's `//p/*[1]`
- the CSS selectors in Tritium allow you to prefix a selector with `>`, as in `$$("> p > :first-child")`; this will be converted into a scoped search (i.e., `./p/*[1]`)
- because CSS selectors are (currently) dynamically converted into XPath, there's a slight performance hit compared to using straight XPath

Comment: Why are CSS selectors converted to XPath?

Comment: Because the current implementation of Tritium uses LibXML, which only supports XPath selectors.